# How to set a maximum limit in WooCommerce orders per item & per day

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to allow only a specific number of orders per product per day on my shop. Any idea which hook do I have to add?

Thanks

Comment: You need to hook into `is_purchasable`.  In there you'll need to get the orders per day with `wc_get_orders()`, and then get the totals per product.  Then set a condition when you return false out of it, kinda like `if ($orderedToday > 10) { return false; }`.
I can add precise code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below uses the product ID to get the total quantity for the current day.  If this is higher than or equal to the `$dailyOrderLimit` that you set (in my example, it's 10), the product cannot be purchased.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preventPurchaseIfDailyOrderLimitReached', 10, 2);

function preventPurchaseIfDailyOrderLimitReached($is_purchasable, $product)
{
    $dailyOrderLimit = 10;
    $productId = $product->get_id();
    $quantityOrderedToday = getDailyOrderAmount($productId);

    if ($quantityOrderedToday >= $dailyOrderLimit) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}

function getDailyOrderAmount($productId)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT sum(product_qty) as quantity_ordered_today FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_product_lookup where product_id= {$productId} and date_created > '{$today} 00:00:00';");

    return $result[0]->quantity_ordered_today;
}
```

*Code is tested and works.  Add it to the `functions.php` file of your child theme.*

If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).